# In React, having a local database displayed through .map function, how can i pass the data.json from parent to child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I would like to pass the data.json from parent Tiles.js to child Info.js. I thought to pass it with props, as React required I guess, but I receive undefined instead of receiving the array of obj of data.json.

****This is what i tried.****

****Here dummy data.json:****

```
[
  {
    "id": "001",
    "title": "#001",
    "cover": "/images/firstimage.png",
    "info": "This is the first image"
  },
  {
    "id": "002",
    "title": "#002",
    "cover": "/images/secondimage.png",
    "info": "This is the second image"
  }
]
```

****Home.js****

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Info from "./Info";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Tiles from "./Tiles";

const Home = () => {
  const [myBool, setMyBool] = useState(true);

  const toggleBool = () => setMyBool(!myBool);

  return (
    <div className="m-5">
      <Navbar />
      {myBool ? <Tiles toggleBool={toggleBool} /> : <Info />}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

****Tiles.js****

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import data from "../data/data";
import Info from "./Info";
import Player from "./Player";

const Tiles = (props) => {
  const [toggleInfo, setToggleInfo] = useState(false);
  const [sendData, setSendData] = useState([]);

  const onToggleInfo = () => {
    setToggleInfo(true);
    setSendData(data);
    console.log(sendData);
  }

  return (
    <>
    
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-3 mt-5">
        {data &&
          data
            .slice(0)
            .reverse()
            .map((item) => {
              return (
                <div key={item.id} onClick={() => props.toggleBool()}>
                  <img
                    alt={item.title}
                    src={`${item.cover}`}
                    className="h-50 w-35 hover:opacity-25"
                    title={item.title}
                    onClick={onToggleInfo}
                  />
             { toggleInfo && <Info dataToInfo={sendData}
                backToTiles={() => setToggleInfo(false)} />}
                </div>
              );
            })}
      </div>
   
      <Player url={data} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Tiles;
```

****Info.js****

```
import React from "react";

const Info = (props) => {

  console.log(props.dataToInfo);
  return (
    <div key={props.dataToInfo.id}>
    <p onClick={props.backToTiles}>GO BACK</p>
   <p>{props.dataToInfo.title}</p>
   <p>{props.dataToInfo.info}</p>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Info;
```

As you can see, I am rendering dynamically Info.js, I am wondering if this can interfere with the passage of props from Tiles.js to Info.js itsel.
If I hard code something in Info.js instead of passing props, It would render the component without any problem. For example:

```
import React from "react";

const Info = (props) => {

  console.log(props.dataToInfo);
  return (
    <div key={props.dataToInfo.id}>
      <p>GO BACK (we should go back to Tiles.js)</p>
   <p>Here should appear the Title of The tile we click on it, passed 
   from data.json</p>
   <p>Here we should have the info of the tile we click in, as well 
   passed from data.json</p>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Info;
```

Comment: How the Tiles and Info components are linked? Where are you rendering Info component?

Comment: @CodeThing I created a new Link to render Info component, but I guess I can also avoid it and just swap the tiles component with the info one without a new Route. The issue i have is this: 
Given data.json.
`[{
    "id": "001",
    "title": "first",
    "cover": "/images/firsttile.png",
    "info": "First tile Info" },
  {
    "id": "002",
    "title": "second",
    "cover": "/images/secondtile.png",
    "info": "Second tiles info" }]`
I render with Tiles component all the data, when i click in one of the image, I would like to show only the info data of the tile selected.

Comment: Okay so on same page you would display tiles and once any tile is selected you will display Info. How would you go back to tiles again then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need data to import in all the component. We can pass it to Info from Tiles.
Please check below. Hope this helps.

App Component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import data from './data/data';
import Info from './Info';
import Tiles from './Tiles';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

  return <div className="m-5">
      {info ? (
        <Info info={info} backToTiles={() => setInfo(null)}  />
      ) : (
        <Tiles data={data} setInfo={setInfo}/>
      )}
  </div>;
}
```

Tiles Component

```
import React from 'react';

const Tiles = ({ data, setInfo }) => {
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-3 mt-5">
      {data &&
        data
          .slice(0)
          .reverse()
          .map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id} onClick={() => setInfo(item)}>
              <img
                alt={item.title}
                src={`${item.cover}`}
                className="h-50 w-35 hover:opacity-25"
                title={item.title}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tiles;
```

Info Component

```
import React from 'react';

const Info = ({ info, backToTiles }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div key={info.id}>
        <p onClick={backToTiles}>GO BACK</p>
        <p>{info.title}</p>
        <p>{info.info}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Info;
```

Comment: still not working, sorry for the late reply, I tried all yesterday and I m on it again today..I rephrase the problem and upload my new code which seems neater and it might show easier where I have the issues.

Comment: Please check updated answer. I think you are making this unnecessary complicated. Source data can just be imported once. You can pass that data down to use in other components.